# Can I suggest JVM when to do the garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I used a event based framework in my java code and there's an event which will triggered when no other events are coming, let's say it's a thread idle event. I think this is a good time to do the GC since doing GC in the time will have no influence on other jobs.

So: 1, Is there any way I can do this?
2, Should I do this?

Comment: You may call `System.gc()`, which _suggests_, but does not guarantee, that the JVM run the garbage collector.  However, most of the time the JVM is pretty smart about knowing what is the the optimal time to run the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

You can tell the JVM to initiate Garbage Collection, But the JVM will decide if and when it will garbage collect. Objects which aren't used anymore, will automatically Garbage collected. If you really want to SUGGEST the JVM to run a Garbage Collection you should use this line of code:

```
System.gc();
```

But as I said, the JVM will see when it isn't used anymore garbage collection it when it wants/needs to.

Comment: Yet this does not trigger Garbage Collection, it only hints the JVM that GC should be run, but there is no way you can force it in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

1) `System.gc()`

2) Should I do it?

> The root of all evil is premature optimization

I doubt it will help and there’s a high chance that it will degrade performance. What do you want to optimize? Throughput or latency? How do you measure it? It is really hard, as with gc you should simulate a production-like environment. System.gc() does a full gc, so it might introduce long pauses where short young generation pauses would have been acceptable.

Note that the G1 garbage collector already automatically adjusts itself to the system load.

Comment: For once this partial quotation is apposite, however here is what D.E. Knuth actually said: 1. 'The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.'

Comment: Another version:  2. 'Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. '